# Logstash not reading file input, not printing to console

Tags: logstash, logstash-file

New to logstash. I am trying to read a simple input and output it to command window.

Logstash version: 2.2.2

Below is my .conf file

```
input {
    file { 
        path => "/my-file-path/logstash-test-data.log"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
}

output {
    stdout{}
}
```

Below is my logstash-test-data.log

```
name=n1,age=a1,id=a
```

This is the output I get after --debug and --verbose

```
$ logstash -f logstash-test.conf --debug --verbose
Settings: Default pipeline workers: 4
Registering file input {:path=>["/my-file-path/logstash-test-data.log"], :level=>:info}
Starting pipeline {:id=>"base", :pipeline_workers=>4, :batch_size=>125, :batch_delay=>5, :max_inflight=>500, :level=>:info}
Pipeline started {:level=>:info}
Logstash startup completed
```

And then nothing happens. I'm expecting the log to be displayed on the terminal.

EDIT:
These are my file permissions

```
ls -l
total 28
-rw-rw-rw- 1 pdutt pdutt     7 Mar  3 14:25 logstash-test-data.log
```

Comment: Try to stdout debug also `   stdout {
      debug => true
   }`

Comment: @7171u Did that. But logstash said that's an configuration error. So I did stdout { codec => rubydebug} instead. No output :/

Comment: it is insanely difficult to perform a file input --> stdout output in logstash (at least in 2.x versions)

Answer (score 0):

remove quotes around "beginning"

Answer (score 0):

Faced simlilar issue. Following modification helped me.

```
start_position => beginning
ignore_older => 0
```